# loop for reading different data types & sizes off very large byte array from file

Tags: c#, .net, large-files, binaryreader

I have a raw byte stream stored on a file (rawbytes.txt) that I need to parse and output to a CSV-style text file.

The input of raw bytes (when read as characters/long/int etc.) looks something like this:

```
A2401028475764B241102847576511001200C...
```

Parsed it should look like:

OutputA.txt

```
(Field1,Field2,Field3) - heading

A,240,1028475764
```

OutputB.txt

```
(Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5) - heading

B,241,1028475765,1100,1200
```

OutputC.txt

```
C,...//and so on
```

Essentially, it's a hex-dump-style input of bytes that is continuous without any line terminators or gaps between data that needs to be parsed. The data, as seen above, consists of different data types one after the other.

Here's a snippet of my code - because there are no commas within any field, and no need arises to use "" (i.e. a CSV wrapper), I'm simply using TextWriter to create the CSV-style text file as follows:

```
if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open)))
            {

                inputCharIdentifier = reader.ReadChar();
                switch (inputCharIdentifier)
                     case 'A':

                        field1 = reader.ReadUInt64();
                        field2 = reader.ReadUInt64();
                        field3 = reader.ReadChars(10);
                        string strtmp = new string(field3);
                        //and so on
                        using (TextWriter writer = File.AppendText("outputA.txt"))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(field1 + "," + field2 + "," + strtmp); // +  
                        }
                        case 'B':
                        //code...
```

My question is simple - **how do I use a loop to read through the entire file**? Generally, it exceeds 1 GB (which rules out File.ReadAllBytes and the methods suggested at [Best way to read a large file into a byte array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030847/best-way-to-read-a-large-file-into-byte-array-in-c?rq=1)) - I considered using a while loop, but peekchar is not suitable here. Also, case A, B and so on have different sized input - in other words, A might be 40 bytes total, while B is 50 bytes. So the use of a fixed size buffer, say inputBuf[1000], or [50] for instance - if they were all the same size - wouldn't work well either, AFAIK.

Any suggestions? I'm relatively new to C# (2 months) so please be gentle.

Comment: Why is `PeekChar()` not suitable? From what you describe each block has an ID char at the start of it, so you could `PeekChar()` just before `inputCharIdentifier = reader.ReadChar()` to see if the loop should be terminated.

Comment: Technically you are correct. The issue is that the data is not 100% kosher - i.e. there are situations where I need to separately deal with the possibility that the character I expect to identify each block is not in the right place. For that reason (alone), I want to try and find a solution that does not use PeekChar().

Comment: @Matthew would this work: [Optimize this method of converting binary to ASCII in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089188/optimize-this-method-of-converting-binary-to-ascii-in-c-sharp?rq=1) specifically the `while (cursor < length)` folllowed by `cursor += sizeof (uint) + sizeof (long) + sizeof(int);` customized by the type of block i'm parsing?

Comment: It'll tell you the length, but if your data isn't 100% kosher there's all sorts of other things that could go wrong. If the data is bad, how do you recover? That's a tricky problem.

Comment: Exactly. I'm trying to sort that out now... But for now, I've decided to use `while (reader.BaseStream.Position != reader.BaseStream.Length)`. Doesn't solve the data issues (that's a separate code block outside case/switch), but the loop aspect is covered. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file byte by byte which you append to the `currentBlock` byte array until you find the next block. If the byte identifies a new block you can then parse the `currentBlock` using you `case` trick and make the `currentBlock` = characterJustRead.

This approach works even if the id of the next block is longer than 1 byte - in this case you just parse `currentBlock[0,currentBlock.Lenght-lenOfCurrentIdInBytes]` - in other words you read a little too much, but you then parse only what is needed and use what is left as the base for the next `currentBlock`.

If you want more speed you can read the file in chunks of X bytes, but apply the same logic.

You said *"The issue is that the data is not 100% kosher - i.e. there are situations where I need to separately deal with the possibility that the character I expect to identify each block is not in the right place."* but building a `currentBlock` still should work. The code surely will have some complications, maybe something like `nextBlock`, but I'm guessing here without knowing what incorrect data you have to deal with.