# how to continue a loop despite error in parsing byte data

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, loops, binaryreader

my question is a continuation of this: ([loop for reading different data types & sizes off very large byte array from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103220/loop-for-reading-different-data-types-sizes-off-very-large-byte-array-from-fil))

I have a raw byte stream stored on a file (rawbytes.txt or bytes.data) that I need to parse and output to a CSV-style text file.

The input of raw bytes (when read as characters/long/int etc.) looks something like this:

```
A2401028475764B241102847576511001200C...
```

Parsed it should look like:

OutputA.txt

```
(Field1,Field2,Field3) - heading

A,240,1028475764
```

OutputB.txt

```
(Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5) - heading

B,241,1028475765,1100,1200
```

OutputC.txt

```
C,...//and so on
```

Essentially, it's a hex-dump-style input of bytes that is continuous without any line terminators or gaps between data that needs to be parsed. The data, as seen above, consists of different data types one after the other.

Here's a snippet of my code - because there are no commas within any field, and no need arises to use "" (i.e. a CSV wrapper), I'm simply using TextWriter to create the CSV-style text file as follows:

```
if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open)))
            {
        while (reader.BaseStream.Position != reader.BaseStream.Length)
            {
                inputCharIdentifier = reader.ReadChar();
                switch (inputCharIdentifier)
                     case 'A':

                        field1 = reader.ReadUInt64();
                        field2 = reader.ReadUInt64();
                        field3 = reader.ReadChars(10);
                        string strtmp = new string(field3);
                        //and so on
                        using (TextWriter writer = File.AppendText("outputA.txt"))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(field1 + "," + field2 + "," + strtmp); // +  
                        }
                        case 'B':
                        //code...
```

My question is based on the fact that some of the raw byte data contains null values, which are difficult to parse through - because there are an **unknown** number of null bytes (or non-null, out-of-place bytes) between consecutive data blocks (each starting with A, B or C if the data blocks are not corrupt).

**QUESTION**

So, **how do I add a default case or some other mechanism to continue with the loop despite an error that might arise because of corrupt or faulty data?** Is the following code something that would work?

```
    inputCharIdentifier = reader.ReadChar();
    ...
    case default:
    //I need to know what to add here, instead of default 
    //(i.e. the case when the character could not be read)
    while (binReader.PeekChar() != -1)
    {
         filling = binReader.readByte();
         //filling is a single byte
         try {
             fillingChar = Convert.ToChar(filling);

             break;
         }
         catch (Exception ex) { break; }
         if (fillingChar == 'A' || fillingChar == 'B')
             break;
```

The remaining part - adding code to each switch case (eg 'A') to continue without stopping the program - is there a way to do this without multiple try-catch blocks? [i.e. the code block character identifier is A, but the bytes after A are corrupt - in which case i need to exit the loop OR read (i.e. skip over) a defined number of bytes - which here, would be known if the message header correctly identifies the remaining bytes.

[Note: Case A, B and so on have different sized input - in other words, A might be 40 bytes total, while B is 50 bytes. So the use of a fixed size buffer, say inputBuf[1000], or [50] for instance - if they were all the same size - wouldn't work well either, AFAIK.]

Any suggestions? Please help! I'm relatively new to C# (2 months)...

Update: my entire code is as follows:

```
         class Program
{
    const string fileName = "rawbytes.txt";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
                    try
        {
            var program = new Program();
            program.Parser();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public void Parser()
    {
        char inputCharIdentifier = 'Z';
        //only because without initializing inputCharIdentifier I ended up with an error
        //note that in the real code, 'Z' is not a switch-case alphabet
        //it's an "inconsequential character", i.e. i have defined it to be 'Z'
        //just to avoid that error, and to avoid leaving it as a null value
        ulong field1common = 0;
        ulong field2common = 0;
        char[] charArray = new char[10];
        char char1;
        char char2;
        char char3;
        int valint1 = 0;
        int valint2 = 0;
        int valint3 = 0;
        int valint4 = 0;
        int valint5 = 0;
        int valint6 = 0;
        int valint7 = 0;
        double valdouble;
        /*
        char[] filler = new char[53];
        byte[] filling = new byte[4621];
        byte[] unifiller = new byte[8];
        //these values above were temporary measures to manually filter through
        //null bytes - unacceptable for the final program
        */
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open)))
            {
                while (reader.BaseStream.Position != reader.BaseStream.Length)
                {
                    //inputCharIdentifier = reader.ReadChar();
                    //if (inputCharIdentifier != null)
                    //{
                        try
                        {
                            inputCharIdentifier = reader.ReadChar();
                            try
                            {
                                switch (inputCharIdentifier)
                                {
                                    case 'A':

                                        field1common = reader.ReadUInt64();
                                        field2common = reader.ReadUInt64();
                                        //unifiller = reader.ReadBytes(8);
                                        //charArray = reader.ReadString();
                                        //result.ToString("o");
                                        //Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
                                        charArray = reader.ReadChars(10);
                                        string charArraystr = new string(charArray);
                                        char1 = reader.ReadChar();
                                        valint1 = reader.ReadInt32();
                                        valint2 = reader.ReadInt32();
                                        valint3 = reader.ReadInt32();
                                        valint4 = reader.ReadInt32();
                                        using (TextWriter writer = File.AppendText("A.txt"))
                                        {
                                            writer.WriteLine(field1common + "," + /*result.ToString("o")*/ field2common + "," + charArraystr + "," + char1 + "," + valint1 + "," + valint2 + "," + valint3 + "," + valint4);
                                            writer.Close();
                                        }
                                        break;


                                    case 'B':
                                    case 'C':

                                        field1common = reader.ReadUInt64();
                                        field2common = reader.ReadUInt64();
                                        //charArray = reader.ReadString();
                                        charArray = reader.ReadChars(10);
                                        string charArraystr2 = new string(charArray);
                                        char1 = reader.ReadChar();
                                        valint1 = reader.ReadInt32();
                                        valint2 = reader.ReadInt32();
                                        using (TextWriter writer = File.AppendText("C.txt"))
                                        {
                                            writer.WriteLine(field1common + "," + result2.ToString("o") + "," + charArraystr2 + "," + char1 + "," + valint1 + "," + valint2);
                                            writer.Close();
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case 'S':
                                        //market status message
                                        field1common = reader.ReadUInt64();
                                        char2 = reader.ReadChar();
                                        char3 = reader.ReadChar();
                                        break;
                                    case 'L':
                                        filling = reader.ReadBytes(4);
                                        break;
                                    case 'D':
                                    case 'E':
                                        field1common = reader.ReadUInt64();
                                        field2common = reader.ReadUInt64();
                                        //charArray = reader.ReadString();
                                        charArray = reader.ReadChars(10);
                                        string charArraystr3 = new string(charArray);
                                        //char1 = reader.ReadChar();
                                        valint1 = reader.ReadInt32();
                                        valint2 = reader.ReadInt32();
                                        valint5 = reader.ReadInt32();
                                        valint7 = reader.ReadInt32();
                                        valint6 = reader.ReadInt32();
                                        valdouble = reader.ReadDouble();
                                        using (TextWriter writer = File.AppendText("D.txt"))
                                        {
                                            writer.WriteLine(field1common + "," + result3.ToString("o") + "," + charArraystr3 + "," + valint1 + "," + valint2 + "," + valint5 + "," + valint7 + "," + valint6 + "," + valdouble);
                                            writer.Close();
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Parsing didn't work");
                                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Here's why the character read attempt didn't work");
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

                            continue;
                            //continue;
                        }
                    //}
                }
            }
            }
            }
```

The error I receive is as follows:

```
    Here's why the character read attempt didn't work

    System.ArgumentException: The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)' fallback 'System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback'.
    Parameter name: chars
    at System.Text.Encoding.ThrowCharsOverflow()
    at System.Text.Encoding.ThrowCharsOverflow(DecoderNLS decoder, Boolean nothingDecoded)
    at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Char* chars, Int32 charCount, DecoderNLS baseDecoder)
    at System.Text.DecoderNLS.GetChars(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Char* chars, Int32 charCount, Boolean flush)
    at System.Text.DecoderNLS.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteCount, Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex, Boolean flush)
    at System.Text.DecoderNLS.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteCount, Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex)
    at System.IO.BinaryReader.InternalReadOneChar()
    at System.IO.BinaryReader.Read()
    at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadChar()
    at line 69: i.e. inputCharIdentifier = reader.ReadChar();
```

Update: A sample file that generates the same error above is at the following link:
http://www.wikisend.com/download/106394/rawbytes.txt

Notice in particular the 8 unexpected null bytes between successive data blocks, **even though the data block header - i.e. *inputCharIdentifier* - is valid**. The number of bytes that follows such a header is **always unpredictable** and generally varies. My issue is that I need to be able to either delete or skip over such a situation when it arises to the next non-corrupt data block available - in the case of the sample file, the last (single) data block that occurs after the 8 out-of-place null bytes.

The 8 null bytes can be located in the file as follows:
Byte Counter: 1056
Line 2, Column 783 (according to Notepad++)

The crux of the problem is that the 8 null bytes can be any size - 3, 7, 15, 50, etc. It is always unknown - as a direct result of data corruption. But unlike "traditional" data corruption, i.e. where a fixed number of bytes, say 50, inside a data block that might be unreadable and can therefore be skipped over (by that exact number of bytes) - the data corruption i face consists of an unknown number of bytes between valid data blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign a case for these situations because the target variable (inputCharIdentifier) is null; thus it is enough with a condition avoiding these cases. I have also included a try...catch, just to make completely sure (any error while performing all the given actions would make the code to automatically skip to the following iteration).

```
try
{
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open), Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        while (reader.BaseStream.Position != reader.BaseStream.Length)
        {
            inputCharIdentifier = reader.ReadChar();
            if(inputCharIdentifier != null)
            {
               switch (inputCharIdentifier)
                 case 'A':
                    field1 = reader.ReadUInt64();
                    field2 = reader.ReadUInt64();
                    field3 = reader.ReadChars(10);
                    string strtmp = new string(field3);
                    //and so on
                    using (TextWriter writer = File.AppendText("outputA.txt"))
                    {
                       writer.WriteLine(field1 + "," + field2 + "," + strtmp); 
                    }
                 case 'B':
                   //code...
            }
        }
    }
}
catch
{
}
```

Comment: ok great, thank you! this did the trick for a block with corrupt data (say, case A with 40 bytes as expected, but 40 unreadable bytes). i now need to address a situation where A is the code block header, but data corruption is more severe - consider, for example, 46 bytes (the length of which I don't know in advance), all either null or unreadable. how do i proceed to the next code block? i'm asking because my peekchar code above will not work when the case identified is correct (or misleading), but the data itself is not [due to data corruption].

Comment: here's the error i receive: _System.ArgumentException: The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)' fallback 'System.Text.DecoderReplace
mentFallback'.
Parameter name: chars_ based on the code at line 61, i.e. `inputCharIdentifier = reader.ReadChar();`

Comment: Emulate these ideas (condition making sure that the given variable is not null + try... catch) at the given level. You can nest one inside other as many conditions and try...cath as you wish.

Comment: In any case, bear in mind that the proposed try...catch takes care of any error happening inside it. So where is exactly located this variable?

Comment: I see the problem. I have modified my answer and put inputCharIdentifier = reader.ReadChar(); inside try. In any case, bear in mind that the try...catch is very inefficient and should be only used under extreme conditions. Instead having a wrong algorithm and letting the catching to take care of everything, you should understand why these errors occur and improve the algorithm.

Comment: at the moment, i end up with an infinite exception loop by putting the `reader.ReadChar()` inside the try-catch block. But specifically, how do I skip over those 46 bytes which are all null or unreadable, but have (an otherwise) valid header? is there a way to use a do while loop in the default case to continue trying to read a character until it hits an A/B block header, and then try to parse data for that particular block? and skip over the null bytes if the block is corrupt?

Comment: Right information has to be got from reader.ReadChar(), if the information is wrong (or null), nothing else can be done (all the code below) other than ignoring. What your error and your update tell is that the variable inputCharIdentifier cannot deal with the information from reader.ReadChar() at some point and thus the reading does not occur and this is the reason for an endless loop (the loop exits when all the reading is done, but if no reading is never done...). If you upload this file and the whole code, I could do some tests and give you a better solution.

Comment: How are you declaring inputCharIdentifier?

Comment: inputCharIdentifier is initialized as a non-consequential character, say 'X' - outside the loop - and then assigned dynamically inside the loop to one of the cases depending on the given data - 'A', 'B', 'C', and so on. I will upload the code to my question soon - thank you for all your help so far!

Comment: To be honest, I don't  understand what you meant with "non-consequential character" (Char?!); I will better take a look at the code and at the problematic file. Bear in mind that the error refers to a problem with the encoding; the file might require a different encoding than the one in the streamreader. This is more a testing and trial-and-error fixing than other thing (= something you should do by your own), but I will take a quick look to see if I can be of any help.

Comment: the non-consequential character refers to initializing the inputCharidentifier as a non-null variable to avoid an error early on. that can be changed if necessary. please take a look at the full code i've uploaded as i've reached a dead end at this point. thanks

Comment: (Initialising a variable is a required pre-action for anything; didn't know that had a special name). This code (+ the proposed inclusions) should be fine to deal with virtually any case under standard conditions. The problem is that you want to deal with corrupted files (whole encoding is not clear to me on account of the error you get). If you want quick and to the point help from me (or any other one) you should include the file which is giving problems.

Comment: I've added the sample input rawbytes.txt file to the question. Please take a look when you can - I've hit a dead end as far as how to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: I will take a look at it and update my answer accordingly ASAP.

Comment: This file works fine on computer or, at least, this is what it seems. Is this the output you were expecting? (first 3 lines)       1234567892,9876543212,PCRSTUVWXY,Z,1236,5680,5602,9802
1234567895,9876543215,PDRSTUVWXY,Z,1239,5683,5605,9805
1234567899,9876543219,PERSTUVWXY,Z,1243,5687,5609,9809  The problem is related with the encoding; you are not setting an encoding type in your binary reader and thus it takes the one by default on your computer (apparently, different than the one on mine). Please, confirm that this is right output (or write the right one) and I will tell you how to get it.

Comment: Yes, I get the same output for the _first few lines_ also, but my program crashes once it hits those 8 null bytes towards the end of the file. Basically, there's a packet after PZRSTUVWXY,Z ... which generates the error. I have still not been able to identify how to skip over such out-of-place bytes, given that the number of those bytes always varies and that they are generally preceded by an otherwise valid `inputCharIdentifier`, i.e. A in this case. What encoding do you (or your system) use for BinaryReader?

Comment: I use ASCII (I have edited my response including it) and I don't get any error (just some weird characters). Understand that the problem you have is basically initialising a char array with a dimension of 3 and then intending to put something with a length of 5; you will have an error for sure. If the part where this value is assigned is also the responsible to let the loop going forward you have a problem whose only solution seems to be "cannot deal with this file". In any case, I hope that ASCII would avoid this problem or any other one and we can finally close this question :)

Comment: Bear in mind that you are not dealing with bits/bytes (easy to manage), but with characters (where the encoding and thus aforementioned differences between the length of the given element and the one expected by the target variable/array do matter).

Comment: Exactly. One last proposal - in brief, is there any way to move the Binary Reader stream counter forward by 1 every time there is an error? In other words, if the assignment of the `inputCharIdentifier` is followed by 7 null bytes instead of the expected 50, can we simply instruct the program to re-try the character assignment 7 more times, until it reaches the next valid data block?

Comment: I cannot come up with a reliable solution for that. See, one thing is having 1-length elements (in case of having a wrong one, you might move to the next one); but characters do not have a constant length (this is precisely what provokes your problem) and thus how could you know the next part to read without knowing the corrupted bit length? (it is not as easy as null = 1; but crash = ?). You might set a secondary loop reading bits to determine the first valid bit, but this does not need to work either. The solution is easy: rely on the right encoding system and everything should be OK.

Comment: Also, I guess that this has got pretty long for a simple question. If you don't think that this answer is adequate (or that it might be improved further), perhaps you should create a "bounty".

Comment: No i can't do that because i don't have sufficient reputation yet to create a bounty. thank you for all your help. I will try and solve the problem externally (i.e. create a situation where the file to be parsed contains no data corruption). In other words, the binary/text file will no longer be "raw bytes" but "pre-processed bytes" instead.

Comment: Welcome. But if this is so important for you and the suggested encoding does not deliver what you want, the solution is clearly going bit by bit. You should focus your tests on corrupted files (these are the problematic ones) and find out whether the bit-to-bit analysis can allow you to recognise different chunks (characters). You should continue focusing on the file you sent and, in any case, on corrupted files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32326/discussion-between-john-and-varocarbas)