# Appending byte and stream

Tags: c#, file-io, stream, byte, arrays

I want to append byte array to stream i opened but just to pass it to hash algorithm and compute the hash, something like:

```
byte[] data;

using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(path), 1200000))
{
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(data + bs);
}
```

I don't know how to do "data + bs" or "bs + data" part... Any idea about this?

Comment: I assume `data` has been filled by then?  What are the ballpark sizes of data and the file?

Comment: this is just an illustration of code, not full code. Data size is 16 bytes. I want to append data array to stream and compute hash.

Comment: btw file size is lets say more than 1 GB. That is why i pass stream as argument.

Comment: Your code _prepends_ the data, not _appends_ it. Please be clear, it might matter.

Comment: And will you run this on a phone/tablet or is reading 1GB into memory no problem?

Comment: I need both, prepend and append. I want it to work for any file even 5 GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't you simply do something like this:

```
public static byte[] MD5Hash( byte[] salt, Stream s , int blockSize )
{
  MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider() ;

  md5.Initialize();

  md5.TransformBlock(salt,0,salt.Length,salt,0) ;

  byte[] buf  = new byte[blockSize];
  int    bufl ;
  while ( (bufl=s.Read( buf , 0 , buf.Length )) > 0 )
  {
    md5.TransformBlock(buf,0,bufl,buf,0) ;
  }
  md5.TransformFinalBlock(buf,0,0) ;

  return md5.Hash ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(data + ReadToEnd(bs));
```

And, your ReadToEnd function:

```
public static byte[] ReadToEnd(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need an `operator+` more than a `ReadToEnd()`. Anyway, with a very big file this isn't efficient/feasible.

Answer (score 0):

```
// here is a quick approach to your original question:
List<byte> raw = new List<byte>(data);
raw.AddRange(File.ReadAllBytes("filePath.ext"));
```

To do this without using List (in other words arrays), use Array.Copy(...) to copy the first and second arrays into a new array of a larger size. (Personally, I prefer Lists in C#, Vectors in C++) If you have 1200000 bytes max and don't want to pull everything from the file, then you could use this code to your advantage: [Best way to read a large file into a byte array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030847/best-way-to-read-a-large-file-into-byte-array-in-c) where `numBytes` is the number of bytes you want to read in.