# Insert Image into SQL Server database using Parameter.Dbtype (stored procedure)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms

I'm trying to insert `IMAGE` into SQL Server database (via a stored procedure), for this I'm using a class that has parameter details and in code behind on button click event I tried to map the values.

```
param = comm.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "Imagedata";
param.Value = Imagedata;
param.DbType = DbType.String;
comm.Parameters.Add(param);
```

I tried using Binary instead of String, I got an error stating that unable to convert String to Byte[]. Datatype I used in SQL was Varbinary(MAX).

```
bool a = false;
String imagefilepath = @fileName;
FileStream imagefile = new FileStream(imagefilepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
Imagedata = new Byte[imagefile.Length];
imagefile.Read(Imagedata, 0, Imagedata.Length);
imagefile.Flush();
imagefile.Close();
a = Users.InsertUser(this.txt_userid.Text.Trim().ToUpper(),
                     this.txt_mobnum.Text.Trim().ToUpper(), 
                     this.txt_name.Text,
                     this.role_cmbox.Text.Trim().ToUpper(), 
                     this.box_branch.Text.Trim().ToUpper(), 
                     this.txt_designation.Text.Trim().ToUpper(), 
                     this.txt_repassword.Text.Trim().ToUpper(), 
                     this.Imagedata.Length.ToString());
```

Stored procedure

```
[dbo].[InsertUser](@UserID varchar(15),@Password varchar(20),@UserName varchar(20),  
@Role varchar(15),@Branch varchar(15),@Designation varchar(15),@Mobilenumber varchar(15),@Imagedata varbinary(MAX))    
as  
INSERT INTO[LBank].dbo.[Login]
           ([UserID]
           ,[Password]  
           ,[UserName]  
           ,[Role]
           ,[Branch]
           ,[Designation]
           ,[Mobilenumber]
           ,[Imagedata]
           )   
VALUES(@UserID,@Password,@UserName,@Role,@Branch,@Designation,@Mobilenumber,@Imagedata);
```

What should be the DbType and how to solve and insert image successfully?

Comment: Am I wrong or the last parameter of the call to Users.InsertUser is the length of the ImageData array instead of a reference to the array?

Comment: What is `Users.InsertUser`? In particular, what is the last parameter to that method?

Comment: Possible please post your stored procedure code here.

Comment: You need to use SqlDbType.Image in param.DbType instead of String. String and Binary Data (image data) is different.

Comment: @Steve Please let me know in detail..  i'm taking in the byte length, if its Reference to the array what should be then.

Comment: @John Saunders Users is a class where I wrote Static bool to insert update edit and delete procedure. the last parameter is the one bugging me. I'm trying to insert image into the database and that parameter refers to Image

Comment: @KrishnanduSarkar "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.SqlDbType' to 'System.Data.DbType'. An exlicit conversion exists (are you misssing a cast?)"

Comment: @Steve thanks for educating me Steve. used reference instead of Length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have to use `SqlDbType` instead of `DbType`.
2. And for File/Image to `Byte Array` you can use `File.ReadAllBytes()` instead of `FileStream` (refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2030865/311255))
3. Pass `Byte Array` instead of Byte Array's `Length` in your `InsertUser` Methods's last parameter.

   ```
       bool a = false;
       String imagefilepath = @fileName;
       ImageData = File.ReadAllBytes(imagefilepath);

       a = Users.InsertUser(this.txt_userid.Text.Trim().ToUpper(),
                      this.txt_mobnum.Text.Trim().ToUpper(),
                      this.txt_name.Text,
                      this.role_cmbox.Text.Trim().ToUpper(),
                      this.box_branch.Text.Trim().ToUpper(),
                      this.txt_designation.Text.Trim().ToUpper(),
                      this.txt_repassword.Text.Trim().ToUpper(),
                      this.Imagedata); //Here you need to pass the byte array not length


       var param = comm.CreateParameter();
       param.ParameterName = "Imagedata";
       param.Value = Imagedata;
       param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;
       comm.Parameters.Add(param);
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: File.ReadAllBytes .. thanks for helping me out worked for me Unable to Vote but really use full :( coz of reputation