# Calculating "time to start" in .WAV files

Tags: .net, audio, wav

I am writing a a rangefinder program at the moment (think sonar). So I fire a pulse of sound and measure how long it takes to come back. Currently, I am simply opening up the sound file and manually measuring the time to rise. I have linked an image for clarity.

[image: waveform]

I'm wondering if there are any .NET libraries to do this sort of thing. I have already looked at NAudio but didn't find anything useful.

It looks like I might have to do this manually, in which case, how do I best go about converting a WAV into a series of raw values (such as each point on the image)? If I can do that I can write my own algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by reading the file into a byte array, extracting some info about it and then searching for the desired sample, which in your case I believe it's the first sample above some threshold.
The first stage is easy, like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030847/best-way-to-read-a-large-file-into-a-byte-array-in-c).
For the second stage, you have to know a bit about `wav` file's structure. As can be seen here - [image: wav file header]
 it contains info about the **number of channels** (in your case it looks like you have only one channel), **sampling rate** and number of **bits per sample**.
After knowing these parameters, you can start to read the audio's data - if it's 8 bits per sample, then every sample is one byte. If it's 16, you'll have to read 2 bytes, and calculate the sample's value, since it is written in little endian format.
When you find that sample number X is the one you're looking for, divide that number by the sampling rate and you'll get the exact time of the sample since the file's start.
The image was taken from [here](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/).