# Upload file to server with form values in WPF C#

Tags: c#

I have:

```
WebClient cl = new WebClient();
NameValueCollection nvm = new NameValueCollection();

nvm["name"] = data.Name;
nvm["description"] = data.Description;
nvm["file"] = // File.OpenRead(data.FilePath) ? or how send file content ?

cl.UploadValues("https://database.org/upload.php", "POST", nvm);
```

My question is: how to send file ? Using stream ? or how ?

Comment: if your file is a text file, just paste the content. If not, you can always get bytes from the file and send the array (take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030847/best-way-to-read-a-large-file-into-a-byte-array-in-c))

Answer (score 0):

UploadValues uploads a NameValueCollection. 
If you wish yo upload a file use `UploadFile(uri, "POST", pathToFile)` instead, or serialize to base64 your file content.

Comment: You didn't read my title... I want to upload file and form values ... not only file

Comment: You didn't read my answer. :) UploadValues will not upload files for you *as files*, only values. Convert your file to a value that NVM can handle. Or use a different method.