# How use .xsd file in WCF service?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xsd

I need to develop WCF service that receive XML from client and process it. I wrote the service and I get the XML as s string something like:

```
 [DataContract]
public class TransferData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string xml;
}
```

But they gave me .xsd file. I am not sure what is this file and how I can use it in WCF service?

Solution can be find in:

[Xml validation using XSD schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572853/xml-validation-using-xsd-schema)

Comment: You can validate the XML using the XSD. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, that is what I want. Can you guild me how use XSD? that is the first time I see this kind f files!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572853/xml-validation-using-xsd-schema

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks it works with that solution.

Comment: Closing because the author answered his own question in the question instead of posting an answer.

Comment: Please have a look at following article:

**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572853/xml-validation-using-xsd-schema**

Answer (score -1):

You may serialize XSD-file to string or byte[] ([Reliable way to convert a file to a byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497997/c-reliable-way-to-convert-a-file-to-a-byte)). However in WCF have limitation file size, for big files used Stream (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: doesn't look relevant to the question