# In UiPath RPA "Convert Text File to Content byte and send it through API"

Tags: c#, uipath, rpa

I'm working in UiPath C# I need to send text file through API call, I need to fetch new file every time and convert to byte and send it through API what activities i need to use to convert it to content byte array and send it.

I have no idea about converting it to bytes.

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497997/reliable-way-to-convert-a-file-to-a-byte

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reliable way to convert a file to a byte\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497997/reliable-way-to-convert-a-file-to-a-byte)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by user [Gubba Nub Nub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9356147/gubba-nub-nub) in his comment. This is (kinda) a duplicate.

You can utilize the Invoke Code activity to run a custom snippet of code. In this situation reviewing the [linked article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497997/reliable-way-to-convert-a-file-to-a-byte) mentioned above will likely solve your answer.

Keep in your mind you will want to pass in and out the variable you wish to convert.

Feel free to give the above a shot and provide more details if you experience any issues!